# Whether or not the date has passed

Tags: javascript, node.js, momentjs

**How to check the time from the base. And current and true/false**

*I record the time in the base like this: `moment().add(1, 'day').format("HH:mm DD-MM-YYYY") // 22:31 27-08-2022`*
*Now the question itself, how do I check whether the number from the reconciled base or not*
below the post is my code. I don't know if I did it right or not. 
I need to check whether the date recorded in the database matches the current date or not. If the date has passed then false

```
    const type = User.findOne({where: { userID: ctx.from.id }})
    
    if (moment().format("HH:mm DD-MM-YYYY") === type.subscription) { 
        await ctx.reply('true')
        // TypeSendController(ctx)
    } else {
        await ctx.reply('false')
        
    }
```

Comment: You should store the timestamps in the database _as_ timestamps. Then you compare them _as_ timestamps. If they're stored in the database as strings, turn them back into timestamps before comparing them with the current time. Once you're dealing with timestamps _as_ timestamps, it's `now.getTime() > subscription.getTime()`.

Comment: Also, moment.js is deprecated. See https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/. If this is new code, don't use it.

Comment: @RogerLipscombe,I didn't understand a bit about the temporary branches. Please tell me more. I am using the base column "varchar(255)" Do I need to update in database datetime?
`await subs.update({
            subscription: moment().add(1, 'day').format("HH:mm DD-MM-YYYY")
        })` This is how I record my subscription times

Comment: @RogerLipscombe, Yes this is new code, I just wrote it, I don't know how to make a subscription system just ^_^